# Browsing back to the root browser container

Tags: sonos

Is there a way to go back to the root browser container when clicking on a container?
I've seen it in the *Radio by TuneIn* service which goes back to the root browser container after choosing a location for the Local Radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with SMAPI currently. The experience you noted is built in to the system specifically.

Comment: Since 'root' id is specified, why not browse back to the root (back to the beginning) when the user clicks a mediaCollection with the root id? Moreover, it makes no sense to browse anywhere else. Next SMAPI version? @MattWelch